# QT How to find untranslated strings

Tags: c++, qt, localization, internationalization

I am testing a QT application I am internationalizing. I think I have found all the strings that need processing through tr() or ::Translate(). I think I have handled all occurrences.

I have gotten back the first rounds of translations (done through Qt linguist tool).

Through QA testing I want to make sure all strings are translated and if possible I would like to easily identify any that are not translated and why.

What tools or methods are available for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered

```
lrelease -markuntranslated <prefix>
```

This takes any strings in the .ts file that are untranslated and prepends `prefix` 
If the label "do it now" is in the .ts file and it is not translated in Qt linguist, then if you run `lrelease` with

```
 -markuntranslated NT-
```

then you will see the label presented when you run the application as 'NT-do it now'.

This makes it obvious for whomever is testing that the problem is a string that has been processed via `::Translate()` or `tr()`, but which has not been translated in QT linguist.

And any wholly original strings in the UI of the running application must thus be fully untouched by any of the QT translation machinery.

see `lrelease -help` for more info.